# Xaml and Layout Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to build a screen using xaml but its slightly off so it is. I can't upload images yet so I have included [this link](http://snag.gy/vKjYe.jpg).

My Problem is the txtWidth text box is going off the screen when it should be big enough just for 3 digits? Does anybody have any ideas.

```
<Canvas Margin="0,0,-249.6,0">
    <ListView Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="48" Height="183" Name="listView1"
            Width="453" 
            SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order" Width="100" 
                       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsOrder}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Display Name" Width="290" 
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Width" Width="50" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsWidth}"></GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Name="moveUpButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Click="MoveUp"  Canvas.Top="50" Content="Move Up" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

    <Button Name="moveDownButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Click="MoveDown" Canvas.Top="80" Content="Move Down" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />


    <Button Name="deleteButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=columnsList, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Click="RemoveColumn"   Canvas.Top="110" Content="Delete" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

    <Button Name="addButton" Click="AddColumn" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="140" Content="Add Item" 
            Height="22" Width="74" />

    <Label Content="Name:" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="250" />

    <TextBox   Name="txtDsiplayName" Text="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"   
            Width="452"  >

    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Width:"   Canvas.Left="470" Canvas.Top="250" />
    <TextBox  Name="txtWdith"  Text="50"  Canvas.Left="470"  Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"  

             />

</Canvas>
```

Comment: Don't use `Canvas` then. It will never restrict its children size. Use other layout panel, like `Grid`

Comment: @dkozl i not sure how to use grid to layout could you give an example please i very new to wpf

Comment: @AwkwardCoder are there any better layout tools i hate vs its so slow im using 2012

Comment: @AwkwardCoder anyway you can do an example using my inline code plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from using a `Canvas` layout to `Grid` layout, there is a very good tutorial [here](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html).

An example of Grid layout is shown below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Name:"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="E-Mail:"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Comment:"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="3" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Margin="3" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Margin="3" />

    <Button Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            MinWidth="80"
            Margin="3"
            Content="Send"  />

</Grid>
```

Comment: can u do example using my inline controls just i not sure how to use the row and column effectivly to re produce the box in picture

Comment: can you look at above please